# Pandas DataFrame won't reindex and transpose, returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the first 9 lines from a .csv into a DataFrame, which works properly:

```
invoice_desc = pd.read_csv('path', sep=',', nrows = 9, header=None)
```

When printed, DataFrame looks like so:

```
                  0                              1
0          ﻿Bill to                        /client/
1        Billing ID            xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
2    Invoice number                     3359680287
3        Issue date                    31-Jan-2016
4          Due Date                    01-Mar-2016
5          Currency                           CURR
6  Invoice subtotal                   9,999,999.90
7          VAT (0%)                           0.00
8        Amount due                   9,999,999.90
```

I now need to pick out certain lines, re-index and transpose so I can insert this into a MySQL db via to_sql():

```
i = ['invoiceNum', 'issueDate', 'dueDate', 'invoiceSubtotal']
invoice_desc2 = pd.DataFrame(invoice_desc.loc[[2, 3, 4, 8],], index = i)
invoice_desc2.transpose()

print invoice_desc2
```

However, that piece of code does re-index but doesn't preserve values and produces this output when printed:

```
                   0    1
invoiceNum       NaN  NaN
issueDate        NaN  NaN
dueDate          NaN  NaN
invoiceSubtotal  NaN  NaN
```

I've been reading about Pandas indexing and slicing [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) but I just can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When you `reindex` it tries to find those labels in your index, they don't exist, if you want to overwrite the index values you should create the df like this: `invoice_desc2 = pd.DataFrame(invoice_desc.loc[[2, 3, 4, 8],])` and then overwrite the index: `invoice_desc2.index = i` and then transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first select subset of `invoice_desc` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), transpose it by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and then change columns by `i`. Creating new `DataFrame` by `pd.DataFrame` is not necessary.

```
print invoice_desc
                  0                    1
0           Bill to             \tclient
1        Billing ID  xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
2    Invoice number           3359680287
3        Issue date          31-Jan-2016
4          Due Date          01-Mar-2016
5          Currency                 CURR
6  Invoice subtotal         9,999,999.90
7          VAT (0%)                 0.00
8        Amount due         9,999,999.90

invoice_desc2 = invoice_desc.loc[[2, 3, 4, 8],:]
invoice_desc2 = invoice_desc2.T
print invoice_desc2
                2            3            4             8
0  Invoice number   Issue date     Due Date    Amount due
1      3359680287  31-Jan-2016  01-Mar-2016  9,999,999.90

i = ['invoiceNum', 'issueDate', 'dueDate', 'invoiceSubtotal']
invoice_desc2.columns = i
print invoice_desc2
       invoiceNum    issueDate      dueDate invoiceSubtotal
0  Invoice number   Issue date     Due Date      Amount due
1      3359680287  31-Jan-2016  01-Mar-2016    9,999,999.90
```

Or first set `index` by `i` and then transpose:

```
print invoice_desc
                  0                    1
0           Bill to             \tclient
1        Billing ID  xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
2    Invoice number           3359680287
3        Issue date          31-Jan-2016
4          Due Date          01-Mar-2016
5          Currency                 CURR
6  Invoice subtotal         9,999,999.90
7          VAT (0%)                 0.00
8        Amount due         9,999,999.90

invoice_desc2 = invoice_desc.loc[[2, 3, 4, 8],:]
i = ['invoiceNum', 'issueDate', 'dueDate', 'invoiceSubtotal']
invoice_desc2.index = i
print invoice_desc2
                              0             1
invoiceNum       Invoice number    3359680287
issueDate            Issue date   31-Jan-2016
dueDate                Due Date   01-Mar-2016
invoiceSubtotal      Amount due  9,999,999.90

print invoice_desc2.T
       invoiceNum    issueDate      dueDate invoiceSubtotal
0  Invoice number   Issue date     Due Date      Amount due
1      3359680287  31-Jan-2016  01-Mar-2016    9,999,999.90
```